# I can't see y values in bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I've made a bar chart but it seems so complicated. My codes:

```
s=list(c.state.unique())
x_state=np.arange(len(s))
y_death=list(c_bar)
#plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
width = 0.75
ind = np.arange(len(y_death))
ax.barh(ind, y_death, width, color="blue")
ax.set_yticks(ind+width/2)
ax.set_yticklabels(x, minor=False)

plt.barh(x_state, y_death)
plt.show()
```

I want to enlarge my graph and I need no to show the state names clearly. Can you please help me? What should I do?  I'm new making to a bar chart.

[image]

Comment: And, kindly do add the values of c, c_bar, etc. At least a subset of values so potential responders can reproduce the bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try different values for the vertical distance, here is an example.

```
 fig.set_size_inches(7, 20)
```